# Which sensitivity analysis is most suitable on cost factors in route planner?

Tags: pgrouting, routing, network-analysis

I am working on developing a route planner with alternative impedance/cost factor (safety of the route).

I am building the application mainly in pgRouting.

As a final step I would like to perform a sensitivity test. This sensitivity test should identify the influence of the different safety parameters (lighting, speed limit, etc) on the routing. The way to do this is to select random origin destination pairs (OD pairs) and see how varying values influence the routing. I did some research on the different types of SA and I cannot conclude which method best suits this particular problem. I've read about rationalized SA (Monte Carlo Filtering), Variance-based SA (Sobol method), Elementary Elements Test/EET (Morris Method), other One-at-a-time (OAT) methods, regression, etc. I am not sure which one is most applicable in this situation.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?